# Добавить товар в корзину, без обновления страницы ASP.Net

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

Есть модель Razor Pages, с post запросом: добавление в корзину

```
public IActionResult OnPost(long productId, string returnUrl, int quantity)
{
    Product? product = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
    if (product != null)
    {
        Cart?.AddItem(product, quantity);
    }
    return RedirectPermanent(returnUrl);
}
```

Также кнопка добавить в корзину

```
<form id="ProductID" asp-page="/Cart" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="ProductID" asp-for="@pr.ProductID" />
   <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" 
   value="@ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.PathAndQuery()" /> //расширение для возврата ссылки
   <span class="card-text p-1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right"
        Добавить в корзину
        </button>
    </span>
</form>
```

При нажатии на кнопку "Добавить в корзину" товар без проблем добавляется в корзину, но проблема в том, что после добавления в корзину происходит обновление страницы, и положение пользователя на странице сбрасывается, кто знает как решить данную проблему? Штудирая интернет, понял что данную проблему решают через отправку запроса через ajax, но не понимаю как это реализовать... Кто шарит, подскажите как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему добавлением к форме class="addToCart"

сам ajax код

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.addToCart').submit(function (ev) {
        var frm = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
        ev.preventDefault();
        console.log(ev);
    });
});
```